# Postgresql Unknow field in function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function in postgresql and i get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "A00" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from "UpdateStatus"(91206618515,"A00")
                                                         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "A00" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 50
```

My function bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateStatus(id bigint,status varchar(3))
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_test
set
 id_status = status
where id_test = id;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

if i put the parameter like this "UpdateStatus"(91206618515,'A00')
i get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function UpdateStatus(bigint, unknown) does not exist
```

Runnig /df +updatestatus

public | updatestatus | void             | cpf bigint, status character

public | updatestatus | void             | cpf bigint, status character varying

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using CAST?

Comment: CAST? Where? Why should a cast be needed? Thank you.

Comment: Use single quotes for parameters. Why did you put function call in quotes? Try this: `SELECT UpdateStatus(91206618515,'A00')`

Comment: I did that in my second call and got the the Does not exist error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bet is you create multiple functions with similar signature. Check your schema functions and drop duplicate function.

Try changing the name of your function for testing. Because your function should work.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/TILOAI61440)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestUpdateStatus(id bigint,status varchar(3))
RETURNS varchar AS $$
BEGIN
     return status;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT TestUpdateStatus(1, 'A001')
```

**OUTPUT** and see how result show lowercase even when define with CamelCase?

[image]

Comment: The problem are the double quotes.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I know that as you can see I use single quotes. But based in comments, OP is also having a problem with `char variant`, I wrote a `DEMO` to show the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you mask strings with single quotes, and you must remove the double quotes around the function name, because you have created it with a case insensitive name:

```
SELECT * from UpdateStatus(91206618515, 'A00')
```

Comment: I got this error
ERROR:  function updatestatusautonomo(bigint, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: SELECT * from UpdateStatus(91206618515, 'A00')
                      ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I cannot see anything like `updatestatusautonomo`in your source code. Try `\df+ updatestatusautonomo` to see the different variants of this functions.

Comment: sorry, the right error: : function updatestatus(bigint, unknown) is not unique LINE 1: SELECT * from UpdateStatus(91206618515, 'A00') ^ HINT: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Try `\df+ updatestatus` ;) Probably postgres interprets the first parameter not as `bigint`; try `SELECT * from UpdateStatus(91206618515::BIGINT, 'A00')`.

Comment: Got this error, ERROR:  function UpdateStatus(bigint, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from "UpdateStatus"(91206618515::BIGINT, 'A...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Please note that I have removed the double quotes in the query. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Yes, i saw, and as you said before the problem was in the cast, but not for the bigint:
SELECT * from UpdateStatus(3137184584,'A02'::CHARACTER VARYING)
Is there a way to avoid this cast?

Comment: `"UpdateStatus"` means **not** the same as `UpdateStatus` in SQL. Define an equivalent function where the first parameter is `INTEGER`.